# Update an UpdatePanel after a button click event

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, vb.net

I would explain better my problem and I would make lots of edits in order to clarify:

Markup

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" />

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" >

                </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Chiudi" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" />
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn_Save" Text="Salva" class="btn btn-success" ValidationGroup="valGroup2" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal"/>



<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" >
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="grd_elenco" runat="server" CssClass="table table-bordered table-hover" data-toggle="modal">

        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>

    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

VB.NET:

```
Private Sub btn_Save_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Save.Click
    Label1.Text = "test"
    UpdateSomeDataInGrid()

    UpdatePanel1.Update()
End Sub
```

I would Update only the `UpdatePanel` with `btn_Save` with a partial postback instead of full postback. I need to Update the panel **after** `UpdateSomeDataInGrid()`, someone know how to do that?

I've tried to add `UpdatePanel1.Update()`, but all page is postback.

Comment: Edit your question with fuller markup. We need to see where Button1 is.

Comment: Going by the markup you've posted, Button1 causes a full page postback hence will update UpdatePanel1 anyway even without any code in your Button1 event handler. Also, since UpdatePanel1 has no content, so how are you determining that it's not getting updated? Please see [our guidance on creating a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: no, button1 doesn't postback page, so I need to postback page with a line of code.

Comment: @RegEdit I've updated my question like you suggested to me. Could help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that btnSave is not inside the UpdatePanel. As things stand, that means it will always cause a full page postback.

To achieve a partial page postback with an UpdatePanel, place the postback control inside the UpdatePanel.

So you need to move btnSave inside the UpdatePanel:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn_Save" Text="Salva" class="btn btn-success" ValidationGroup="valGroup2" />
         .
         .
         .
```

Alternatively, if it suits your design better, move your entire div that contains btnSave inside the UpdatePanel:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
         .
         .
         .
```

Or place btnSave in its own UpdatePanel. This will avoid the full page postback, while your handler can still update UpdatePanel1.

Comment: If I put the button inside the update panel it doesn't be in the modal box. So, how can I use it in the modal box if it is already in the update panel?

Comment: @PietroZ. I've updated my answer with 2 suggestions about that.

Comment: With a little adjustment for my specific case this worked. Thanks